# Lodash. How to get array values from object if you know array keys?

Tags: javascript, lodash

For example, you have an object.

```
{ id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
```

How to get an array from the object if you know array keys? You have array keys

```
['firstName', 'lastName']
```

and you should get array

```
['John', 'Doe']
```

I use **Lodash**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you `_.at()`:

```js
const obj = { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' };
const keys = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

const result = _.at(obj, keys);
console.log('RESULT:', result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need lodash.

Just use `Array.prototype.map` to get values from key array.

```js
const obj = { id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' };
const filterKey = ['firstName', 'lastName'];

console.log('FILTERED:', filterKey.map(key => obj[key]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const keys = Object.keys({ id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' });
const values = Object.values({ id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' });

console.log(keys)
console.log(values)
```

You don't need to use Lodash, using plain javascript will do it.
Use `Object.keys()` for getting all the keys of an object and `Object.values()` to get an array with all the values that an object has.

Comment: In my case, I should have an array without id and use array keys.